# Will Flyway execute all migrations from the beginning on an existing database?

Tags: java, mariadb, database-migration, flyway

I have a a strange question to ask. I started working on a project and I need to integrate flyway to make it execute any new migrations on application start-up. The flyway dependency and config exists, pointing at a batch of migration scripts, but these were previously executed against the target 'by hand' without flyway having been used. The prod database full of user data. I can not tell you why it was organised like this.

What I want to do is to integrate flyway to make it check that migration folder and to add a command to the pipeline. And I have a concern that if I don't configure flyway properly will it execute all those migrations from the beginning on start-up? (this can corrupt existing data) Or it will it only execute newly added migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch application against clean test database, Flyway will run all migrations and save the records to `flyway_schema_history` table. Then you manually create `flyway_schema_history` on prod database, populate it with records taken from test table. When you launch prod application, Flyway will scan `flyway_schema_history` table and consider that all migrations are already executed, and will not run your scripts so data will not be corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Flyway will by default try to execute all migrations that haven't been logged as run in the flyway_schema_history table.

But... there is a [flyway baseline](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline) feature which instructs Flyway to ignore any migrations that have a version equal to or lower than a specified version.

So assuming the "already run migrations" are given an earlier version number (which is baked into the filename), and you ensure that you set a baselineVersion to be a number that is above these run migrations, then you should be good to go.